# How to get the form with input type password from a page with multiple forms using Javascript DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, dom

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Form.html</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      body {
        margin: 30px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="form1">
      <div id="fullnameIDdiv">
        Full Name: <input type="text" name="fullname" /><br />
      </div>
      <div id="usernameIDdiv">
        Username: <input type="text" name="username" /><br />
      </div>
      Password: <input type="password" name="password" /><br />
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>

    <form id="form2">
      <div id="firstName">
        Full Name: <input type="text" name="fname" /><br />
      </div>
      <div id="lastName">
        Username: <input type="text" name="lname" /><br />
      </div>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

For Example,
In this page there are two forms. I want to get the form that has the `input` `type = password`. I don't want to get the form using its ID(`getElementById`) because I want to get a more general solution for getting the form, with `input` `type = password` out of multiple forms.

I have looked into `document.forms.elements` but I am not able to get to the solution. Please help.

Edit:
In this I have given a sample html code but my question is rather general. The answers given before this edit have used `.parentNode()` to get the parent node of the `input` tag. But if the `input` is under the tags such as `<span>` or `<section>` then the `.parentNode()` would not give the `<form>` tag. Keeping that in mind, how to get the `form` tag with `input` `type = password` from a page with multiple forms using Javascript DOM?

Answer (score 0):

As your HTML stands now, you can try using `querySelector()` and `parentNode` like the following way:

```js
var passForm = document.querySelector('input[type=password]').parentNode;
console.log(passForm);
```

```html
<form id="form1">
  <div id="fullnameIDdiv">
    Full Name: <input type="text" name="fullname" /><br />
  </div>
  <div id="usernameIDdiv">
    Username: <input type="text" name="username" /><br />
  </div>
  Password: <input type="password" name="password" /><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<form id="form2">
  <div id="firstName">
    Full Name: <input type="text" name="fname" /><br />
  </div>
  <div id="lastName">
    Username: <input type="text" name="lname" /><br />
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: What is the input are in <span> <section> etc and then the whole thing in a form like that of google.com login page. In that case the form would not be the the parentNode right? What should I do then.

Comment: @Ashutosh, that's why I have mentioned *As your HTML stands now*, you could either update the question with the new mark up or ask a separate question.

Comment: @Ashutosh, if the element is another element then you have use another `.parentNode` like `document.querySelector('input[type=password]').parentNode.parentNode`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is with jQuery.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1">
        <div id="fullnameIDdiv">
          Full Name: <input type="text" name="fullname" /><br />
        </div>
        <div id="usernameIDdiv">
          Username: <input type="text" name="username" /><br />
        </div>
        Password: <input type="password" name="password" /><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
      
      <form id="form2">
        <div id="firstName">
          Full Name: <input type="text" name="fname" /><br />
        </div>
        <div id="lastName">
          Username: <input type="text" name="lname" /><br />
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
      <script>
          $("form>input[type='password']").parent();
      </script>
</body>
```